# Replacing ceiling fan with remote Control and keep wall switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

I'm replacing ceiling fan.
I have the following wall controls as indicated in the picture below:
[image: Wall controls]
I must say I haven't much experimented with the functionality of each one, however I can say for sure that the switch on the right is sort of a master switch, turning it ON or OFF basically restores the previous operation of the ceiling fan or turns off both fan and light. That's really all I know.

On the ceiling I have 4 wires coming out - black, red, white, green.
I also have remote control, which presented in the picture below:
[image: Remote Control]
Remote control has the five wires total.
There are two "inbound" wires - black and white.
There are three "outbound" wires (exactly matching the wires on the fan itself) - black, blue and white.

My goal, ideally is to restore the functionality as before. However when I removed the fan I saw that the black wire in the ceiling was not connected. What I would like to achieve is to be able to control the fan with remote, as well as from the switch in the wall.

If I connect all wires (ceiling -> remote control -> fan) based on colors, what do I do with the red ceiling wire?

Could you please recommend how best this can be accomplished?
Thank you.

Edit:
Added wall switches photos.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside both the switch and fan boxes?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Here you go

Comment: You control the fan speed with the remote or with the wall switch, not both.

Comment: Does it mean I can safely remove the left part of the wall switch panel?